# Problema com background em svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Eu estou estudando um pouco sobre *svg* e achei incrível as formas gigantes nos sites, porém estou com muita dificuldade para reproduzir corretamente. Eu criei uma forma de tamanho 693x768 que irá cortar uma página, porém não consigo fazer com que ela sempre preencha 100% de altura. Aqui imagens para mostrar exatamente o que está acontecendo:
[image: Imagem com 1366x768]
Assim é como o site fica aberto normalmente em um monitor 1366x768, porém observe o que acontece quando mudo o tamanho do monitor para 1024x768:
[image: Imagem com 1110x768]
Meu código CSS é basicamente esse:

```
#bloco {
  background: url("../imgs/form.svg") no-repeat right;
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

E o `.svg` é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="693.000000pt" height="768.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 693.000000 768.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <g transform="translate(0.000000,768.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#333" stroke="none">
    <path d="M3562 7638 c-36 -79 -3534 -7583 -3548 -7610 l-15 -28 3466 0 3465 0 0 3840 0 3840 -1675 0 -1674 0 -19 -42z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Resumindo

Como faço pro background pegar toda a altura sem sofrer redimensionamento dessa maneira?

### Observação

- Fiz a imagem primeiro no Photoshop e usei uma ferramenta para converte-la em `.svg`. Suspeito de que se o código `.svg` for arrumado talvez o erro suma.
- O background só é redimensionado quando a largura vai diminuindo e a altura da janela não acompanha (como se fosse uma razão matemática).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui! O problema estava tanto no CSS quanto no SVG. Eu fiz uma outra imagem pelo photoshop com o tamanho de 1366x768 e converti em SVG usando [essa ferramenta online](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg), tudo igual a antes (essa imagem nova é do tamanho da tela com a imagem que mencionei na pergunta, aquele corte). Quando apliquei a imagem e fiquei testando, percebi que o que estava acontecendo é que o background (SVG) estava se redimensionando normalmente, porém quando ficava muito pequeno ao ponto de sair da razão 1366x768, ele se redimensionava proporcionalmente, mantendo a proporção, logo, diminuindo também a sua altura. O que fiz para arrumar o problema foi o seguinte:

### .svg

Primeiro editar o `.svg` para que sua largura e altura peguem 100% do elemento:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
```

E então especificar o `viewbox`, que seria como a imagem deve se comportaria em um tamanho estipulado previamente (como um tamanho normal, não sei/consigo explicar). No meu caso 1366x768, já que a imagem tem esse tamanho. Agora vem a parte que faz o que eu precisava, mudar/adicionar o atributo `preserveAspectRatio` com o valor de `none`. Isso faz com que a imagem possa ser redimensionada livremente sem manter a proporção inicial. Tendo assim minha tag dessa forma (omiti algumas tags aqui nesse exemplo):

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1366 2304" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

---

### CSS

Também dei uma editada no CSS, primeiro defini que o elemento teria 100% de altura e largura (ele pega toda a janela, se você ainda não percebeu pelo tamanho da imagem). Após isso chamei o background, deixei para ele se não repetir, coisa normal:

```
#elemento {
  background: url("elemento.svg") no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Com isso a imagem já se ajusta automaticamente! O código CSS ainda não está pronto, fazendo uns testes vi que o Firefox modifica a propriedade `background-size` para `auto auto`, deixando minha imagem não posicionada corretamente. Para resolver eu simplesmente mudei o valor para `100% 100%`, assim o svg iria cobrir todo o espaço necessário. CSS final:

```
#elemento {
  background: url("elemento.svg") no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%; /* Firefox */
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

### Referências

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container
- https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/